# Issues with my regex in c#, works with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I use this regex for my email validation

`/.+@.+\..+/i`

I can't get it to work on my server side though. I tried this so far

```
var pattern = @"^.+@.+\..+i$";
var pattern = @".+@.+\..+i";
```

I get 0 results [trying it](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) (also in my code). Any ideas? Not sure if it helps but the requirement is to allow `a@b.c` so 1 char, one @ and at least one '.'.

Comment: What does the `i` in the pattern means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj to be honest I have no idea :). I got this regex from somebody. I'm really bad at regex.

Comment: @dejan.s - regex parsing machine are different for javascript and other servers. You need to find the appropriate one. What programming language do you use on server?

Comment: `i` means 'Ignore letter case' if you use it in this way: `var reg=/[a-z]+/i` ,same as `var reg=/[a-zA-Z]+/`

Comment: insensitive casing (/{match}/ I/G (seearch global, insensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be the `i`; you don't mean "ends with `i`" (which is `i$`), etc - in the javascript, the trailing `.../i` means "case insensitive" - but there is nothing there to *be* case sensitive, so just remove the `i` (from both would be fine, but from the C# at least). You should also remove the `^` and `$` that you added from nowhere. For completeness, `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is how you ignore case in .NET `Regex`.

```
var pattern = @".+@.+\..+";
```

Comment: I'll try that out. Would you recommend the `^` and `$` in C#? Actually not sure what it does?

Comment: @Dejan.S yes; they mean "start" and "end"; they aren't in the javascript version, so the javascript version matches "*has* this pattern"; with the `^`/`$`, this becomes "*is* this pattern".

Comment: @Dejan.S I need to be careful how I say this, but: if you weren't sure what they did, why did you add them? rather than, say, doing a 2 second google search to *find out* what they did?

Comment: I have no knowledge when it comes to regex. I mean I used it before like got done of the net. Now always seen the `^` `$`, but the validation before it didn't use it so I just wanted to check. Reason I ask here instead of google is that other can take knowledge from it. Because let's be honest asking this question I did is rookie :)

Comment: @MarcGravell while doing validations, it's better to add start and end anchors.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that depends entirely on what you are validating, and what the validation rules are; "better" is an entirely meaningless phrase without the import context of "better at X".

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `i` character from the regex and then add start, end anchors to your pattern,

```
@"^.+@.+\..+$";
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE3dU7/6)

Comment: `Just remove the i and add start,end anchors,`

Comment: k; I missed the "add"; but *why* are you adding them? they aren't in the js version...

Comment: +1. The other got accepted just becuse of the more extensive answer. Thanks Avinash.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

**C#:**

```
bool validateEmail(string email) 
{ 
    var re = new Regex(@"^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@""]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@""]+)*)|("".+""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$") ;
    return re.IsMatch(email);
}
```

see here :[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript/46181#46181)

Comment: Before I downvote - OP said the example works in javascript, but doesn't work in C#.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Just Add the C# version :)

Comment: I'm not sure "replace everything you have" is always the right answer to "this works for what I want in js; help me get it working in C#".